# How to check which statement has thrown exception?

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

I have a statement like this.

I just want to know which of the two assert statement has thrown the exception.

```
try:
    assert re.search("xyz", statement)
    assert re.search("abc", statement)
except AssertionError:
    print "AssertionError : Expected Error message not found"
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you want to distinguish between the two, use separate `try/except` blocks for each statement.

Comment: The most simple solution is to remove the `try` / `expect`.

Comment: @KlausD. Fair comment, but perhaps Logesh wishes to continue execution after any `AssertionError`s in that block are raised; of course, that's generally not a safe strategy, but it's sometimes useful, as in my demo.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [The assert statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) docs, you can give an expression after the assertion test expression; that second expression will be passed in the AssertionError. Here's a simple demo:

```
for n in (-5, 10, 20):
    try:
        assert 0 <= n, '%d is too low' % n
        assert n <= 10, '%d is too high' % n
        print('%d is ok' % n)
    except AssertionError as err:
        print "AssertionError:", err
```

**output**

```
AssertionError: -5 is too low                                                                                                                  
10 is ok                                                                                                                                       
AssertionError: 20 is too high
```

---

That second expression doesn't have to be a string, it can be anything. Since assertions should only be used to verify program logic, not to validate user data, I generally don't bother passing a nicely-formatted string, I just pass a tuple containing the relevant values, and maybe an identifying string. Eg,

```
assert (a * b > c), ('Bad product', a, b, c)
```

Comment: [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) library in python provides many utilities to extract more information of the raised exception

Answer (score 1):

You could use functions from the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module. For example, [`extract_tb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) returns a list of tuples (named tuples in Python 3.5 and newer) representing the stack trace entries. Each tuple contains a line number as well as the source text line (if available).

```
import traceback

try:
    assert 1
    assert None
except AssertionError as e:
    for x in traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__, limit=-1):
        print(x.lineno, repr(x.line)) # Prints 5 'assert None'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to print the last raised exception with `traceback.print_exc()`. An example:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> try:
...    a = 1 / 0
... except:
...    traceback.print_exc()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

There is also `traceback.format_exc()` in case you don't want to print.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to differ the exceptions?Then [Getting exception details in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887038/getting-exception-details-in-python) can help you.
Copying the answer here:

```
import sys
try:
   assert re.search("xyz", statement)
   assert re.search("abc", statement)
except  AssertionError:
   type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

Then you can print out the info.