# What exactly happens when you create an alias of the Exception class?

Tags: python, exception

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The above code prints `division by zero` as one would expect. But if we try to print without creating the alias:

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception:
    print(Exception)
```

It simply prints `<class 'Exception'>`. What is happening here? The `as` keyword is used to create an "alias". If the error message "division by zero" is an attribute of the `Exception` class, then why does creating an alias make it equal to said attribute?

Is it possible to print the error message without creating the alias?

Comment: Well, `Exception` is `Exception`. The `as e` assigns *the specific* exception instance to a variable.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15887038/5320906) for some answers to the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) of Python states this:

> The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name. The variable is bound to the exception instance which typically has an args attribute that stores the arguments. For convenience, builtin exception types define **str**() to print all the arguments without explicitly accessing .args.

It means that the variable that is passed after the name of `Exception` has additional attributes to display the specific exception occured.